# Designing warning/confirmation dialogue box

Tags: gui-design, design, popup, confirmation, alerts

Currently working on a design which will prompt a dialogue box with confirmation message. Just some background on the design, when user attempt to add or delete data from a grid, a dialogue box will appear warning the users that if they were to add or delete now, all changes made will get refreshed not unless if they save it first.

I am now looking for examples on how should I word my dialogue box. I've search for some examples from Microsoft but I doesn't seems to be quite fit. Is there anywhere I can search for better example and what should I need to focus on when designing the warning/confirmation dialogue box?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZEbq1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: You might consider avoiding confirmations, using "undo" instead. Clicking confirmation popups can get irritating, and people tend to click to dismiss the dialog without reading.

Answer (score 2):

For an alert, the main elements and particularities are:

- urgent character;
- requiring user's attention;
- inform about an event / a situation.

Design elements:

- simple design;
- an overlay can help the user focus on the question;

Material design example:

[image: alert-material-design]

[Personal approach:](https://dribbble.com/shots/2731720-Alert-Popup-Design)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [Material Design - Dialogs](https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#) might prove useful.

Some key points to pull out from that documentation:

- Your buttons should be labeled with the action the user is performing by clicking the button.
- The progressive action (typically the add/delete labeled button) is on the right, while the action to remain in the current state (typically a cancel button) is to the left of that. (I'm basing this off the documentation linked above, I don't want to start a holy war.)